# Hibernate Cirteria - resultTransformer with set of children

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteria

i'm having trouble with Hibernate Criteria on tables with multiple children.

This is my criteria:

```
crit = session.createCriteria(PrescRicette.class)
            .createAlias("prescEpisodi", "episodi", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("prescEsenzioni", "prescEsenzioni", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("prescRicetteAmb", "ricetteAmb", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("prescRicetteFarma", "ricetteFarma", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("prescRicettePrescrizioni", "ricettePrescrizioni", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("prescIdentificativiRicette", "prescIdentificativiRicette", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("episodi.prescAssistiti", "assistito", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("ricetteAmb.prescFascePriorita", "fascePriorita", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("ricetteFarma.prescNoteCuf", "noteCuf", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("ricettePrescrizioni.prescPrescrizioni", "prescrizioni", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("prescrizioni.prescPrestazioni", "prestazioni", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("prestazioni.prescBranche", "branche", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("prestazioni.prescPrestazioni030", "prestazioni030", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("prescrizioni.prescFarmaci", "farmaci", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("farmaci.prescFarmaGruppiEquiv", "farmaciGruppiEquiv", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("farmaci.prescFarmaci030", "farmaci030", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("farmaciGruppiEquiv.prescGruppiEquivalenza", "gruppiEquiv", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("prescEsenzioni.prescTipiEsenzioni", "prescTipiEsenzioni", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("assistito.idPazAnaPaz", idPaz))
            .add(Restrictions.isNotEmpty("prescIdentificativiRicette"))
            .addOrder(Order.desc("dataEmissione"))
            .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(PrescRicette.class));

    ricetteDB = crit.list();
```

I've done this because for performance reason I need to get data in non lazy mode and LEFT JOIN between tables.

This is the error:

```
Could not find setter for prescTipiEsenzioni on class org.oshc.hibernate.modules.gestioneRicette.PrescRicette
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for prescTipiEsenzioni on class org.oshc.hibernate.modules.gestioneRicette.PrescRicette
    at org.hibernate.property.ChainedPropertyAccessor.getSetter(ChainedPropertyAccessor.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CriteriaLoader.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:629)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1596)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    at org.oshc.bf.modules.gestioneRicette.command.RicettePersistenceManager.recuperaRicettePaziente(RicettePersistenceManager.java:170)
    at org.oshc.bf.modules.gestioneRicette.services.RecuperoRicetteService.eseguiCommandRecuperaRicettePaziente(RecuperoRicetteService.java:97)
    at org.oshc.bf.modules.gestioneRicette.services.RecuperoRicetteService.recuperaRicettePerPaziente(RecuperoRicetteService.java:62)
    at org.oshc.pf.modules.gestioneRicette.dwr.GestioneRicetteDAO.getRicettePerStoricoPrescrizioni(GestioneRicetteDAO.java:269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.oshc.pf.util.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:868)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:663)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[WARN] DefaultRemoter - Method execution failed:  org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for prescTipiEsenzioni on class org.oshc.hibernate.modules.gestioneRicette.PrescRicette
    at org.hibernate.property.ChainedPropertyAccessor.getSetter(ChainedPropertyAccessor.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CriteriaLoader.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:629)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1596)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    at org.oshc.bf.modules.gestioneRicette.command.RicettePersistenceManager.recuperaRicettePaziente(RicettePersistenceManager.java:170)
    at org.oshc.bf.modules.gestioneRicette.services.RecuperoRicetteService.eseguiCommandRecuperaRicettePaziente(RecuperoRicetteService.java:97)
    at org.oshc.bf.modules.gestioneRicette.services.RecuperoRicetteService.recuperaRicettePerPaziente(RecuperoRicetteService.java:62)
    at org.oshc.pf.modules.gestioneRicette.dwr.GestioneRicetteDAO.getRicettePerStoricoPrescrizioni(GestioneRicetteDAO.java:269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.oshc.pf.util.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:868)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:663)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

[WARN] BaseCallMarshaller - --Erroring: batchId[25] message[org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for prescTipiEsenzioni on class org.oshc.hibernate.modules.gestioneRicette.PrescRicette]
```

Now, the problem is that i don't want the entity prescTipiRicette be set on PrescRicette, and I can't find the error on the criteria.

Without the resultTransformer fields get mapped just fine, but the root entity gets replicated for each child.
With .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY) the root element does not get replicated, but each root has only one child.

The entity are just too much to be copied and pasted in this question, so in some more snippet is needed just ask, I will add them.

Thanks in advance,
Mattia

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
createAlias("prescEsenzioni.prescTipiEsenzioni", "prescTipiEsenzioni", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
```

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for prescTipiEsenzioni on class org.oshc.hibernate.modules.gestioneRicette.PrescRicette
```

The AliasToBeanResultTransformer is trying to convert map prescTipiEsenzioni to your class org.oshc.hibernate.modules.gestioneRicette.PrescRicette but failing in the process because its missing a setter for prescTipiEsenzioni.

Can you check if PrescRicette has prescTipiEsenzioni property and corresponding fields/setters?

Comment: No, the PrescTipiEsenzioni entity is not directly connected to PrescRicette.
The PrescRicette entity has private PrescEsenzioni prescEsenzioni; and inside prescEsenzioni there is PrescTipiEsenzioni.